# Python - Arranging CSV in the same order

Tags: python, csv

Say that we have two csv files. Each csv file contains two columns. Say the first column shows the `name` and the second column shows the `age`.

I would like to have the order of the names in the second file the same as the first file, provided that all the names are unique.

So, say for instance we had the first file having the following values:

```
Name     Age
Adam     34
Paul     23
Ahmad    22
Yasmine  43
```

And, say that the second file looked as follows:

```
Name     Age
Adam     34
Yasmine  43
Ahmad    22
Paul     23
```

How can we reorder the elements of the second file to have the same ordering as the first file?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you try and what did not work?

Comment: Is a `left join` gonna work?

Answer (score 2):

Append each row of each file into a nested list structure using a for loop.

So [[Adam, 34], [Paul, 23]....].

Because with lists, you can sort to where order matters, whereas dictionary there is no order.

Next, you need a nested for loop.  The outer for loop iterates through each list element that you want to copy (first file).  Now, the inner loop will iterate to search the second list (second file) to find if the same element exists.  If exists, append to a new list, and you'll have the same order.

This would be terribly inefficient if you had many entries..especially the nested for loop (quadratic runtime).  But just a thought to get you thinking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried once using a dictionary and another using a list, but get the same answers and the wrong orderings. Do you have a script that would return the correct values?